# Raise an event if observable list count is not updating

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project in windows form application,in which i have created an event.This event is raised when i click on any page in browser(i.e. FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete). Now, i am adding the data into an ObservableCollection whenever the event is firing.To check whether list count is increasing i am using CollectionChanged event of ObservableCollection.What i want is to fire an event if list count is not increasing.

```
ObservableCollection<Session> Sessions = new ObservableCollection<Session>();
public void FetchSession() {
        #region AttachEventListeners        
        FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += new SessionStateHandler(FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete);
        Sessions.CollectionChanged += Sessions_CollectionChanged;

}
void Sessions_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   //this fires when Collection count changes
}

void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Session oSession)
{
     Monitor.Enter(Sessions);
     Sessions.Add(oSession);
     Monitor.Exit(Sessions);
}
```

Their is nothing available in ObservableCollection class that can tell me that Collection count is not increasing. How can i do this?

Comment: You know, which event You subscribed to ? Collection CHANGED. What Do You think happens, when the count does not increase ? There is no change. I am afraid, You might want to implement an async method, also.
It might be possible to get rid of collection changed and instead  create two own events, like StartObserving and EndObserving, and compare the amount of entries in Your collection in both methods, async, if preferred.

Comment: can you please give me some sample for it.

Comment: So, You have Montior.Enter... Monitor.Exit... You could save a row counter  of Your Sessions-collection before entering it. And You could query this counter after exit. If they are equal, do, what You want, if not, do something different.

Comment: I didnot get it what you said. Can you explain me

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of `ObservableCollecton<T>` and add your own custom event when the Count hasn't changed between calls to `CollectionChanged` events. So you basically keep a private field that stores the Count of the collection and on the next CollectionChanged event you compare the current Count with the previous count. If they are equal you raise your custom event.

A possible implementation looks like this:

```
public delegate void CountEqual(object sender, EventArgs e);

public class ObservableCountCollection<T>: ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public CountEqual CountUnchanged;

    private int _previousCount;
    private object locker = new object();

    public ObservableCountCollection()
    {
        this.CollectionChanged += ObservableCountCollection_CollectionChanged;
        _previousCount = 0;
    }

    void ObservableCountCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool raiseEvent = false;
        var unchanged = CountUnchanged;
        lock(locker)
        {
            raiseEvent = _previousCount == this.Count;
            _previousCount = this.Count;
        }
        if (raiseEvent && unchanged!=null)
        {
            unchanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` type does have an [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction(v=vs.110).aspx) property. For this collection I think you could also do

```
raiseEvent = (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace || 
              e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move);
```

so you wouldn't need to keep the count and lock construct but I didn't test how that works if you're able to call `AddRange` on a collection. I leave that for any follow-up questions.